# How do I check if a method is public in Java at run-time

Tags: java

To display all the methods of the class, whose name is entered through user-input at run-time in the form of a String, I do:

```
// String s is the class name entered

if (Class.forName(s).getDeclaredMethods().length > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Class.forName(s).getDeclaredMethods().length; i++) {
            System.out.println(Class.forName(s).getDeclaredMethods()[i].toString());
    }
}
```

However, if I need to display just the public methods, what do I add?

Comment: You do realize that `Class.forName` and `getDeclaredMethod` are not only expensive but writing it repeatedly makes the code hard to read.

Comment: You can use the method  [getModifiers()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getModifiers())

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I might write it like this.

```
for (Method m : Class.forName(s).getDeclaredMethods()) {
    boolean isPublic = (m.getModifiers() & Modifier.PUBLIC) != 0;
    System.out.println(m + " isPublic: " + isPublic);
}
```

Answer (score 17):

You can try like this:

```
if (Modifier.isPublic(method.getModifiers())) 
{
    //Yes the method is PUBLIC         
}
```

Refer [getModifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getModifiers()):

> Returns the Java language modifiers for the method represented by this
>   Method object, as an integer. The Modifier class should be used to
>   decode the modifiers.

Comment: Much more readable and intuitive solution than the marked one

Answer (score 2):

You can get the modifiers using `getModifiers()`. Here is an idea (not tested)

```
for(Method m : Class.forName(s).getDeclaredMethods()) {
    if(m.getModifiers() == Modifier.PUBLIC) {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

There is also a `isPublic` method in the `Modifier` class ([doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html#isPublic(int)))